# Iam getting an error trying to verify credentials of my TWITTER API

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

The code i used is given below:

```
import twitter

consumerkey ='xxx'
consumersec ='xxx'

accesstok ='xxx'

accesssce ='xxx'

**api =twitter.api(consumer_key=consumerkey,consumer_secret=consumersec,access_tokenkey=accesstok,access_token_secret=accesssce)**

print(api.VerifyCredentials())
```

The error that i got is

> api =
>   twitter.api(consumer_key=consumerkey,consumer_secret=consumersec,access_tokenkey=accesstok,access_token_secret=accesssce)
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable